# How can I represent a loop in a sequence diagram in Microsoft Visio 2007?

Tags: uml, visio, sequence-diagram

I am drawing a sequence diagram in Microsoft Visio 2007 and I want come message calls to be represented in a loop.But I can not find any shape in the shapes provided.How can I represent a loop in visio??
Need emergency help....please..........and shaped available to download and use??
Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Draw a rectangle around the group of calls involved. Outside the box put text that says, "LOOP: [condition]" and fill in the condition.  This will get you close to the UML for loops.

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to select the shapes that should be contained in the loop and then from the Visio menu select Insert -> Container. 
The heading on the container can then be set to "loop" or what is preferred.
I personally likes the alternating container form.